# How is airline fuel hedging actually done?

Tags: airline-operations, fuel, airport-operations, refueling

When airlines refuel at the airport are they all billed at the same rate on the day? Similar to cars at a gas station?

For example if Southwest has hedged and paying a dollar less per gallon than its competitors, how is that dollar realized? Are they billed at a different rate? Or is fuel hedging purely a stock market contract game where the profits or losses are just added/subtracted to the actual fuel costs after the fact at the accountancy/financial results reporting stage?

It’s usually described that airlines hedge against WTI or similar but as they are actually buying kerosene I assume the hedging must be an indirect insurance vs a literal contract to the supplier of the fuel?

Many questions but all essentially ask how does fuel hedging work in practice? I understand the basic concept of buying options at a particular price and selling above below the spot price at a future date but how does that actually work for airlines in practice at the fuel pump?

Answer (score 3):

I am far from an expert on this subject, but I'd imagine it works something like this:

- Airline A contracts with FBO B (or the airport) to purchase 50,000Kg of fuel per day for \$1.99 per Kg.
- N12345, owned by Airline A, pulls up to gate A27, FBO B dispatches a truck to the gate and pumps 10,000Kg into the plane, making a note of the date/time/gate #, how many Kg were pumped, and the tail number of the plane in question.

  - This is repeated several times per day for the various aircraft of Airline A that need to be refueled.
- At the end of the month, FBO B sends a bill to Airline A for \$2,985,000 for 50,000Kg of fuel at \$1.99/Kg per day times 30 days, along with an itemized invoice showing how much fuel was actually pumped into which aircraft.

  - If Airline A actually used less that 50,000Kg of fuel for a day, they probably still have to pay for it per the contract.
  - If Airline A used *more* than 50,000Kg of fuel on a given day, there is an extra charge, at a pre-agreed price (maybe the same \$1.99, maybe \$2.50, who knows - it depends on the contract) for each additional Kg of fuel pumped.
- Airline C may have negotiated a contract with FBO B for fuel *at the same airport* and agreed to pay \$2.15 per Kg for their fuel.

  - It could be the same 50,000Kg/day as Airline A, but they negotiated at a different time when it appeared that prices would be higher in the future.
  - It could be that they negotiated for a smaller quantity of fuel, so have to pay a higher price for a lower usage.
  - It could be that their negotiators just aren't as good as those at Airline A, and that they need to go poach some better people for their purchasing department.
- At the end of the month, FBO B sends an invoice to Airline C for \$3,225,000 (assuming the same 50,000Kg/month) for their fuel with adjustments for any overage.

*Note: all names/prices/quantities/tail numbers/etc. are purely made up for this example and have little to no bearing on reality.

Comment: Excellent answer, but @federico, is speculation about accounting practices on topic?

Comment: Thanks, @MichaelHall. I'd agree that this may just be a general accounting/finance question. It could go to [money.se], but it's not exactly _Personal_ Finance. It _might_ be on topic at [quant.se], but I don't understand enough about finance to know one way or the other on that. It's definitely _not_ [travel.se]! :)

Comment: And personally I'd like to see it stand, my comment stems from another thread that in my opinion was worth keeping open.  I know people aren't always going to agree, but sometimes the enforcement seems a bit arbitrary.  Sorry to use this as an "example", I will delete my comments at an appropriate time...

Comment: No worries! I've been known to jump to "migrate it!!" a little too often. ;)

Comment: @FreeMan it's definitely not quant.

Comment: @hobbs - my understanding of finance ends when my checkbook balances and I know I've spent less than I've made in any given month. I'll take your word on it. ;)